License of a demo application for job interviews
I am a computer programmer and I have almost finished to work on a demo application that is based on some qt and fftw software packages available in the official Ubuntu (Linux) repositories.
The demo is intended to show my skills to potential employers and I would like to share only the application with them, not the source code. I want them to use it only for the recruiting phase and prevent them to use/redistribute it for commercial and non-commercial purposes.
What kind of license (if it exists) should I use? I did some search on the web but I could not find any valuable answer.

Both of those libraries are (L)GPL so you would likely need to release your application under (L)GPL which would require giving source code to anyone you give the binary to.  The open source stack would likely be a better place to discuss licensing options.

Wouldn't it be a red flag to an employer, that you don't want to show them the code you wrote?

@kaya3 Yes, but I had a bad experience in the past when I showed the code. Maybe I had to be more careful and I would like to protect myself this time.

Someone who's going to hire you as a programmer, wants to see what your code looks like. It's not enough that it runs.

This question now has an answer on Open Source SE.
